# sockets.connect() returns None while the connection is created

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

Good evening

Since the last time that i used the sockets module, after trying to write similar code, it doesn't work.

I'm trying to create a simple client/server app.

Server accepts the connection but then the client somehow exits.

```
# server_host = '', server_port = 9999

connection_info = (self.server_host, self.server_port)  
connection = self.sock.connect(connection_info)
```

But then, i can't use any socket method, since connection is None.

Looking through the docs, i couldn't find why

```
connect()
```

returns None.

Im working on localhost, using ss/netstat shows that the port is open.

What am i missing here?

Comment: What's the type of the `self.sock`?

Comment: If that `self.sock` is a normal `socket` object, then the docs don't mention any connection object being returned by the `connect` method

Comment: it's a simple tcp client/server, so
    
   self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

Comment: Read the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket-objects - the socket object itself is supposed to be used for sending and receiving data. That corresponds to the Unix syscalls. You don't have a separate `connection` object

Comment: That's what i have troubles with, i can't send nor receive data, since the the result from connect 
is None.

Comment: Did you try doing `self.sock.send()` afterwards? Or `recv`

Comment: Ok, i have found the error.
You helped me understand that instead of connection i should use self.sock

connect() just connects, doesn't return anything apperantly, so i should just connect and then proceed sending/receiving data with the socket object.

Comment: Yups. The `connect` is a `void` method. The thing is, in python, you can assign a variable to the result of a `void` method call - all that does is set that variable to `None` - that's what you were seeing

Comment: Exactly, and i couldn't figure out what was wrong, since the articles/blogs i was checking, were all using this method, unless i was seeing everything wrong.